# Back slashes doubling in file directory in for loop

Tags: python, xml, parsing, filepath, elementtree

So  what I am trying to do with this loop is while I loop through the files with a certain extension I am pulling the information I want from those files and saving them. My loop works for the first file. But I am getting an error message after the first file. I know the directory path does not exist because for some reason it is doubling the about of \ as shown in the picture below. **How do I get rid of the doubling of the back slashes?**

```
import os  
    import pandas as pd 
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    #This variable was created to save time by staring it at the WI folder and go from there.
    current_dur = r'Workplace Investing'
  
#logic to search through the directories.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_dur):
    for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.ldm') or file.endswith('.cdm') or file.endswith('.pdm'):
                full_file_name = "'" + os.path.join(root, file) + "'"
                print(full_file_name)
                print(os.path.join(root,file))
                #for i in file_results:
                    #WE are parseing it.
                tree = ET.parse(full_file_name)
                    #We then get the root.
                gotten_root = tree.getroot()
.....
```

Comment: I recommend you look at the standard package pathlib and its Path object.

Comment: Do you mean this documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the double backslashes, since the 'r' before your path is correctly doing its job escaping them. The problem is in the `'`.

Try using just

```
full_file_name = os.path.join(root, file)
```

Comment: Well it gets to the second value. But after that I am getting a "ParserError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0"

Comment: May you provide more info? Where are you getting this error?

Comment: It seems to be an error related to parsing of your file. If it is, I'd suggest you to ask a new question specific to your new problem (unless you solve it by yourself, maybe exploiting similar questions here)

Comment: Okay will do. Thank you.

Comment: If this answer does solve your question, you may consider accepting it, as it might be helpful for future developers. If you have asked a question related to the new error you're getting, you may also add it as a reference for people facing similar problems. Good luck!